# Easiest way to move a program to another hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-registry

World of Warcraft is just getting too big for my SSD. I want to move it to one of my other drives. What's the best way to do this w/out mucking the registry and all that? I'm running windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just pick it up and move it to the other drive (drag and drop style).  Then run the WOW launcher from the new location.  If anything needs to be fixed registry wise, it will fix it then.

It's been a while since I've played WoW, but this has worked for me in the past.  The only caveat is you might need to recreate any shortcuts (Desktop/Start Menu).

Comment: Nah.. turns out it fixed the short cuts too. Thanks man! A lot less painful than I thought it would be.

Comment: Glad it turned out real easy to do for ya.  Feel free to accept my answer. ;)

Comment: I tried to.. but you answered too quickly, it wouldn't let me.

Comment: No sweat, thanks for coming back and accepting; just trying to get my SU rep up!

Comment: There is a registry key that World of Warcraft needs to point to the proper location. Fortunately if you run the `Launcher` as an administrative user it will update the registry key automatically.